# Angular2+ : Displaying ElasticSearch results from multiple indices in a single component template

Tags: angular, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

This project is written using the MEAN stack, and the requirement is a search box that will find all relevant documents across the entire site. So, searching for 'John Smith' will find, for example, the user profile for John Smith AND a blog post that mentions John Smith by name, AND an invoice created by John Smith. I can successfully search all indices and types and return the results to a heterogeneous array (`results[]`) in my component, but my issue is: each result element comes from a different index/type with widely differing field structures, so this template works specifically for blogpost elements:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results">
  <p>Title:  {{ result._source.detail.title }}</p>
  <p>Author:  {{ result._source.detail.author }}</p>
  <p>Content:  {{ result._source.detail.content }}</p>
</div>
```

...but if a result element comes from a different index/type, this template won't render correctly because, for example, there is no field named 'detail.title' in any model except `blogpost`. Any fields that exist in other index/types but not in blogpost are of course not displayed either.

I'm using npm packages mongoose, elasticsearch, and mongoosastic with the `.synchronize()` method to create indices on each model. I can use `curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'` to see that all the correct indices are present. In other words, search works for all indices, and all types, but I can currently only display the results correctly for one index/type at a time by fitting the html template to that index/type.

The search method in my service looks like this:

```
Search(_index, _field, _queryText): any {
    return this.es_client.search({
      // index: _index,
      // type: _type, // by not specifying type, we are searching all.
      filterPath: ['hits.hits._source', 'hits.total', '_scroll_id'],
      body: {
        'query': {
          'multi_match': {
            'query': _queryText,
            'type': 'best_fields',
            'fields': [*.*]
          }
        }

      },
      '_source': ['*.*']
    });
  }
```

...so I have the most generic, all encompassing query returning all fields from _source.

How should I handle the problem that, in the results from searching several indices, every _source has different fields within?

Comment: So you have a template based on a type in an index, but you want to use it to render results from other types in order indices?

Comment: Correct. Results from one specific index (the one that has the exact fields I've specified in my template, above) are shown correctly. Results from any other index are structured differently so they don't get rendered and I don't know how to handle that...in my template? By restructuring the indexes somehow? A special calculated field in each model? With so many possibilities, I'm looking for the MEAN stack best practice.

Comment: Why don't you limit _source to these fields instead of[' *.*'], That would be the best option here

Comment: I'm not sure I've made my requirement clear. The template above will display blogposts correctly, because blogposts have `detail.title`, `detail.author`, and `detail.content`. Now, within the same results[] array populated by an elasticsearch query against all indices and types, there are also `user` elements, containing `username`, `email`, `detail.favoritecolor`, etc. These fields are completely different from the ones in blogpost elements. How can I display both (and several others) in the same *ngFor loop?

Comment: You'll probably have to do this dynamically, see here for example https://webcake.co/object-properties-in-angular-2s-ngfor/